# ActiveRecord caching and update_attributes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, concurrency

If a model changes an attribute locally, then changes it back, ActiveRecord doesn't send the change to the DB. This is great for performance, but if something else changes the database, and I want to revert it to the original value, the change doesn't take:

```
model = Model.find(1)
model.update_attribute(:a, 1) # start it off at 1

# some code here that changes model.a to 2
model.a = 2 # I know it changed, reflecting my local model of the change

model.update_attribute(:a, 1) # try change it back, DOESN'T WORK
```

The last line doesn't work because AR thinks in the DB it's still 1, even though something else changed it to 2. How can I force an AR update, or update the cache directly if I know the new value?

Side note: the code that changes it is an update_all query that locks the record, but it has side effects that mess up the cache. Multiple machines read this table. If there's a better way to do this I'd love to know.

```
Model.update_all(["locked_by = ?", lock_name], ["id = ? AND locked_by IS NULL", id])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `reload` method for this.

```
model.reload(:select => "a")
```

**OR**

You can try the `will_change!` method(Its not clear how your change happens. But you can try this method).

```
model.update_attribute(:a, 1) # start it off at 1
model.a_will_change! #fore warn the model about the change
model.a = 2  #perform the change
model.update_attribute(:a, 1)
```

Comment: Does this do a database operation? I know what the value should be, so I'd rather set the cache directly

Comment: Yes. It does. That's why I have reduced the number of fields selected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Harish Shetty is correct, you need to call reload on the reference, however I found a better way to do that automatically.

In your model you want to reload attribute to, create a after_update callback and call reload directly there, like so:

```
after_update :reload_attr
def reload_attr
    reload select: "attr"
end
```